# Get JSON from URL by PHP

Tags: php, json, getjson

I have a URL that returns a JSON object like this:

```
[
    {
        "idIMDB": "tt0111161",
        "ranking": 1,
        "rating": "9.2",
        "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
        "urlPoster": "http:\/\/ia.media-imdb.com\/images\/M\/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_UX34_CR0,0,34,50_AL_.jpg",
        "year": "1994"
    }
]
```

URL : http://www.myapifilms.com/imdb/top

I want to get all of the `urlPoster` value and set in a array's element, and convert array to JSON so echo it.

How can I do it through PHP?

Comment: have you tried `json_decode()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.myapifilms.com/imdb/top');

$array = json_decode($json);

$urlPoster=array();
foreach ($array as $value) { 
    $urlPoster[]=$value->urlPoster;
}

print_r($urlPoster);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do something like that :

```
<?php 
$json_url = "http://www.myapifilms.com/imdb/top";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply decode the json and then pick whatever you need:

```
<?php
$input = '[
        {
                "idIMDB": "tt0111161",
                "ranking": 1,
                "rating": "9.2",
                "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
                "urlPoster": "http:\/\/ia.media-imdb.com\/images\/M\/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_UX34_CR0,0,34,50_AL_.jpg",
                "year": "1994"
        }


]';

$content = json_decode($input);
$urlPoster = $content[0]->urlPoster;
echo $urlPoster;
```

The output obviously is the URL stored in that property:

`http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_UX34_CR0,0,34,50_AL_.jpg`

*BTW: "The Shawshank Redemption" is one of the best films ever made...*

Answer (score 0):

This how you do the same thing with array_map function.

```
<?php

#function to process the input
function process_input($data)
{
 return $data->urlPoster;
}

#input url
$url = 'http://www.myapifilms.com/imdb/top';


#get the data
$json = file_get_contents($url);

#convert to php array
$php_array = json_decode($json);

#process the data and get output
$output = array_map("process_input", $php_array);


#convert the output to json array and print it
echo json_encode($output);
```